# can't attach file 'drop' event when using jQuery on()

Tags: jquery, event-handling, drag-and-drop, typeerror

I'm trying to use [the jQuery `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach the `drop` event to the browser window when doing **file drag and drop**...

```
$(window).on('drop', function(event) {

    var dt = event.dataTransfer;
    var fileList = dt.files;

    // do stuff with the file list...
});
```

... but I'm getting a `TypeError`:

[image: TypeError]

This is happening whenever I try to attach `drop` to `window` or `document` or `document.body`. However, there is no problem if I attach the `drop` event using a custom JavaScript function...

```
function attachEvent(element, event, fn) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, fn);
    }
};

attachEvent(window, 'drop', function(event) {

    var dt = event.dataTransfer;
    var fileList = dt.files;

    // do stuff with the file list...
});
```

Any idea why this is happening? What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to attach the `drop` event to either `window` or `document` or `document.body` with jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message or the `arguments` array of the `TypeError` would make it easier to tell where the problem is occurring, but it's *likely* that your problem's not really happening on bind, but inside your callback.

jQuery uses a [normalized event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). That object doesn't have a `dataTransfer` property, so your `var dt = event.dataTransfer` line is making `dt` undefined. When you go to access the `files` property of the undefined `dt` in the next line, you get a `TypeError`.

You can access the native, non-normalized event object with all its "normal" properties from `event.originalEvent`, so when using jQuery, you'd want to do:

```
$(window).on('drop', function(event) {

    var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    var fileList = dt.files;

    // do stuff with the file list...
});
```

Comment: @John... thank you! I wasn't aware of the "normalized event object" that jQuery was using. Thanks for pointing this out! n00b mistake :D

Comment: @John 18 months later and another upvote for you :-)